# Trace distance between "weighted" Hermitian matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

The trace norm for a matrix $\mathbf{A}$ (also known as [Shatten 1-norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schatten_norm)) is defined as follows: $\|\mathbf{A}\|_1=\operatorname{trace}[\sqrt{\mathbf{A}^*\mathbf{A}}]$.  It yields a useful distance measure between matrices $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$, called *trace distance*: $\|\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{B}\|_1$.

Suppose that $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are Hermitian, and $a,b>0$ are positive scalars.  Is the following true:

$$\|a\mathbf{A}-b\mathbf{B}\|_1\leq \max(a,b)\|\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{B}\|_1?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it cannot be true. Take $A=B$ but $a\ne b$. Then
$$
\|aA-bB\|_1 = |a-b| \|A\|_1 \not\le \max(a,b) \|A-B\|_1 = 0.
$$